# Ajax Rating Control in updatepanel in repeater

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have Ajax Rating Control within Repeater. When I don't use updatepanel then WaitingStarCssClass not work, and when I put rating control into updatepanel, then rating control not work.
My code example:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="CommunitiesListRepeater" runat="server" 
    OnItemCommand="_CommunitiesList_ItemCommand" 
    onitemdatabound="CommunitiesListRepeater_ItemDataBound">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr >
        <td style="border-top:1px solid gray;border-right:1px solid gray;padding-top:10px;" valign="top">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
                <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server"
                            CurrentRating='<%# GetCommunityUserRating(Eval("Reference").ToString())%>' AutoPostBack="true"
                            MaxRating="5" OnChanged="Rating_Changed"  Tag='<%# Eval("Reference").ToString()%>'
                            CssClass="ratingStar"
                            StarCssClass="ratingItem"
                            WaitingStarCssClass="Saved"
                            FilledStarCssClass="Filled"
                            EmptyStarCssClass="Empty"
                            style="float: left;" />



        <asp:Label ID="CommunityRating" runat="server" Text='<%# WriteAvgRating(Eval("UserRating"), Eval("Reference").ToString())  %>' Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="X-Small"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>

        </td>

    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void Rating_Changed(object sender, RatingEventArgs e)
    {
        string reference = ((AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)sender).Tag;
        int rating = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value);
        ...
        FillRepeater(); // reload data in repeater


    }
```

How to use Rating Control in Repeater properly?